# matlab: get multiple mouse coordinates displayed on one screen

Tags: matlab, coordinates, mouse, identify

I have two mouse pointers displayed om the screen (currently by using TeamPlayer application), and i would like to know if there is any way in MatLab that I can identify and read the mouse coordinates of each pointer.

i know how to get the coordinates of a single pointer on screen using:

```
    get(0,'PointerLocation');
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that MATLAB will be able to capture the extra mouse pointer when it is not in "remote controlled" mode. On the machine which share its screen, unless you specifically "Allow control" for the remote user, the (remote) pointer displayed is just a small graphic overlay provided for convenience by Teamviewer, it does not behave at all like a mouse pointer and is not seen as such by your OS, even less by MATLAB.